# Gzip chunked data decompose in C++

Tags: c++, gzip, inflate

I'm trying to Gzip chunks of compressed data, while I don't have it all available at a given time. I saw many examples with files, but I'm not able to convert it for my needed.

I know that it should be done in a loop but to simplify the question I'm trying with 2 parts.

```
z_stream bid_strm;
bid_strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
bid_strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
bid_strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
bid_strm.avail_in = 0;
bid_strm.next_in = Z_NULL;
bid_strm.total_in = 0;

if (inflateInit2(&bid_strm, 16) != Z_OK) 
    cout << " inflateInit failed" << endl;

size_t out_size = 64000;
unsigned char decompressed[64000];

//FIRST Chunk
u_char compressed[part1_comp.size()]; 
memcpy(compressed, part1_comp.c_str(), part1_comp.size());
size_t compressedSize = part1_comp.size();

bid_strm.avail_in = part1_comp.size();
bid_strm.next_in = compressed; 

bid_strm.avail_out = out_size;
bid_strm.next_out = decompressed;

int ret = inflate(&bid_strm, Z_NO_FLUSH);
size_t have = out_size - bid_strm.avail_out;

cout << "HAVE: " << have << endl;
cout << "RET: " << ret << endl;

//SECOND Chunk
u_char compressed2[part2_comp.size()]; 
memcpy(compressed2, part2_comp.c_str(), part2_comp.size());

bid_strm.avail_in = part2_comp.size();
bid_strm.next_in = compressed2;

bid_strm.avail_out = out_size;
bid_strm.next_out = decompressed + have;

ret = inflate(&bid_strm, Z_NO_FLUSH);
have = out_size - bid_strm.avail_out;
cout << "HAVE: " << have << endl;
cout << "RET: " << ret << endl; 

(void)inflateEnd(&bid_strm);
```

The first chunk is decompressed correctly, but I can't find a way to decompress the second one. 
Return value of Z_DATA_ERROR(-3) received, but if I set both chunks in the same array and inflate all at once, everything works fine.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://zlib.net/manual.html) for `deflateInit2`: _The `windowBits` parameter is the base two logarithm of the maximum window size (the size of the history buffer). **It should be in the range 8..15** for this version of the library._  The value you gave (`16`) is not in the range 8..15.

Comment: I saw that, but for some reason, windowBits = 16 is able to decompress the data I receive, in case I use a deferent number I get a Z_DATA_ERROR.

Comment: Also in the gzip source code, I sow that they use examples with values greater than 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found in the documentation. The issue was windowBits.

```
inflateInit2(&bid_strm, MAX_WBITS | 16)
```

solved the issue.

Choosing windowBits:

1. deflate format: use wbits = -zlib.MAX_WBITS
2. zlib format: use wbits = zlib.MAX_WBITS
3. gzip format: use wbits = zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16

Documentation: https://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Advanced